# laravel websocket can’t establish a connection to the server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm using beyondcode laravel websocket. server dashbord and broadcasting is working, but can't show messages on view. i use to show laravel Echo. but i have error.

broadcasting.php

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'useTLS' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

event (notice.php)

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class notice implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('my-channel');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
  {
      return 'my-event';
  }
}
```

boostrap.js

```
/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

// try {
//     window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
//     window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

//     require('bootstrap');
// } catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    // forceTLS: true
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001
});
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 200;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .top-right {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 18px;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 84px;
            }

            .links > a {
                color: #636b6f;
                padding: 0 25px;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: .1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .m-b-md {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Docs</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Blog</a>
                    <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://vapor.laravel.com">Vapor</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
        <script>
            Echo.channel('my-channel')
            .listen('my-event',(e) => {
                console.log(e);
            })
            // window.Echo.channel('my-channel').listen('my-event', e => {console.log(e);});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

error

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:6001/app/abcdef?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.0&flash=false. app.js:24819:15
The connection to wss://localhost:6001/app/abcdef?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.0&flash=false was interrupted while the page was loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inorder to send data in `websocket` you need to create public property on event

```php
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class notice implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    
    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->message = "Hello";
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('my-channel');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
  {
      return 'my-event';
  }
}
```

in `__construct()` you can accept data and assign to public property

then when u will listen for that event you will get data

**in bootstrap.js**  ref link https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher

```js
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

Comment: public property mean?

Comment: i set that __construct() now. but error is  Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:6001/app/abcdef?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.0&flash=false. app.js:24819:15
The connection to wss://localhost:6001/app/abcdef?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.0&flash=false was interrupted while the page was loading.

Comment: websockest dashboard is running. when I call event, it is shown on the dashboard.

Comment: i want to show on boadcasting message using channel listen and print on console log. error on that part

Comment: 4001,"App key abcdef not in this cluster. Did you forget to specify the cluster?" what is this error

Comment: remove `cluster` from `bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have well configured your broadcast, bootstrap.js and .env files and For some cases you have just to run websockets with sudo:
sudo php artisan websockets:serve