# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: CORS issue when accessing external resources on an external device, despite working locally

Tags: laravel, cors

I get the following error messages

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy does not allow reading the external resource at http://localhost:5173/resources/js/app.js. (Reason: CORS request failed). Status code: (null).
Source URI of module is not allowed in this document: 'http://localhost:5173/resources/js/app.js'.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy does not allow reading the external resource at http://localhost:5173/@vite/client. (Reason: CORS request failed). Status code: (null).
Source URI of module is not allowed in this document: 'http://localhost:5173/@vite/client'.
```

This code functions correctly on my local machine. However, when I connect to an external device, I encounter the error messages mentioned above. I am unsure about how to address this issue.

I have removed the API from my cors.php file
cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

And this is my custom cors.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,X-Token-Auth,Authorization')
        ->header('Accept', 'application/json');
    }
}
```

This is my app.js

```
import './bootstrap';

console.debug('init app')

EchoClient.listen('notifications', 'NewLogEvent', (ev) => {
    console.warn('Received event', ev)
    if (ev?.logData?.description) {
        alert(ev.logData.description)
    } else {
        console.warn('Invalid logData event.')
    }
})
```

Bootstrap.js

```
/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

import axios from 'axios';

window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.EchoClient = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: false,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws'],
});
```

API call:
[image]

Maybe problem:
[image]
Diffrent host
[image]

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Docker.composer.YML

```
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.3
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.3/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - soketi
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    soketi:
        image: 'quay.io/soketi/soketi:latest-16-alpine'
        environment:
            SOKETI_DEBUG: '${SOKETI_DEBUG:-1}'
            SOKETI_METRICS_SERVER_PORT: '9601'
            SOKETI_DEFAULT_APP_ID: '${PUSHER_APP_ID}'
            SOKETI_DEFAULT_APP_KEY: '${PUSHER_APP_KEY}'
            SOKETI_DEFAULT_APP_SECRET: '${PUSHER_APP_SECRET}'
        ports:
            - '${PUSHER_PORT:-6001}:6001'
            - '${PUSHER_METRICS_PORT:-9601}:9601'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

.ENV

```
PUSHER_HOST=soketi
PUSHER_APP_ID=app-id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=app-key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=app-secret
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST=localhost
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Do you have control both over the site that sends the request and the site that receives the request?

Comment: Yes, extra information the local gets the message in app.js, but the external one doesn't receive the message in app.js, which will give the core error mentioned above.

Comment: That's cool. Next question: do you see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers inside the site that you are sending the request to?

Comment: @B.Simsek, what type of app are you developing? A SPA? what domains are you using?

Comment: @suxgri I am using my local netwerk domain so my IPv4 address, on docker.

Comment: @lajosArpad The call is sent from an API that is inside a Raspberry Pi. However, I can also send the call from my browser when I put the API URL inside; everything is fine there. The main error is in retrieving the message on a externe computer or phone.

Inside the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: i see a *

Comment: Can we be sure that your Raspberry sends the request to the correct URL?

Comment: @lajosArpad, yes, I am certain. However, I've encountered something; perhaps that could be the issue. Please refer to the image above. The data sent with the API call is correct; the only problem is that I don't receive the message on an external device.

Comment: If it's a different server, then it might have different settings. Can you log something at your access control allow origin part of the code and somehow detect when was it triggered by the Raspberry PI? Then you could debug this.

Comment: @LajosArpad, after further investigation, I've identified that the issue originates from the vite.config.js file see image above. This file give the javascript code a localhost:5173 why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Refrence: [laravel websocket can’t establish a connection to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63913130/laravel-websocket-can-t-establish-a-connection-to-the-server)

```
window.EchoClient = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: false,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws'],
});
```

Add server inside your vite.config.js

```
server: {
    hmr: {
        host: '192.168.2.17',
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times CORS-ORIGIN error occurs due to browser cache or other browser issue's
Please Install Cors-Origin extension:
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf
it may help you.